# Data retrieval failed for the subreport RDLC

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have the following code:

```
private void CreateExcel(string fileName)
        {
            var operationDate = System.DateTime.ParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            var ds1 = new _spAvailabilityEventDailyReport1TableAdapter();
            var ds2 = new _spAvailabilityEventDailyReport2TableAdapter();
            var ds3 = new _spAvailabilityEventDailyReport3TableAdapter();
            var ds4 = new _spAvailabilityEventTotalTableAdapter();
            var ds5 = new _spAvailabilityNoteDailyReportTableAdapter();
            var ds6 = new _spAvailabilityDailyReportTableAdapter();
            var ds7 = new _spAvailabilityReadingTotalTableAdapter();
            var ds8 = new _spAvailabilityEventSum1TableAdapter();
            var ds9 = new _spAvailabilityEventSum2TableAdapter();
            var ds10 = new _spAvailabilityEventSum3TableAdapter();

            //default margin setting
            string outputType = "Excel";
            string pageHeight = "11.69in";
            string pageWidth = "8.27in";
            string marginTop = "0.3937in";
            string marginBottom = "0.3937in";
            string marginLeft = "0.3937in";
            string marginRight = "0.3937in";
            string reportPath = Server.MapPath("~/rdlc/dailyavailability.rdlc");
            try
            {
                //search setting margin report & kind output export -> for parameter 2nd render RDLC
                var xml = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(reportPath);
                var matches = Regex.Matches(xml, @"<(?<property>PageHeight|PageWidth|TopMargin|BottomMargin|LeftMargin|RightMargin)>(?<value>[^<]+)</\k<property>>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                {
                    if (!match.Success)
                        continue;
                    switch (match.Groups["property"].Value)
                    {
                        case "PageHeight":
                            pageHeight = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                            break;
                        case "PageWidth":
                            pageWidth = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                            break;
                        case "TopMargin":
                            marginTop = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                            break;
                        case "BottomMargin":
                            marginBottom = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                            break;
                        case "LeftMargin":
                            marginLeft = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                            break;
                        case "RightMargin":
                            marginRight = match.Groups["value"].Value;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception) { }
            string reportType = string.IsNullOrEmpty(outputType) ? "Excel" : outputType.Trim().ToUpper();
            string encoding;
            string deviceInfo = string.Format(@"<DeviceInfo>
    <OutputFormat>{6}</OutputFormat>
    <PageWidth>{0}</PageWidth>
    <PageHeight>{1}</PageHeight>
    <MarginTop>{2}</MarginTop>
    <MarginLeft>{3}</MarginLeft>
    <MarginBottom>{4}</MarginBottom>
    <MarginRight>{5}</MarginRight>
</DeviceInfo>", pageWidth, pageHeight, marginTop, marginLeft, marginBottom, marginRight, reportType);


            var rds = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityEventDailyReport1", (DataTable)ds1.GetData(operationDate)); //fill data report in parameter
            var rds2 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityEventDailyReport2", (DataTable)ds2.GetData(operationDate)); //fill data report in parameter
            var rds3 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityEventDailyReport3", (DataTable)ds3.GetData(operationDate)); //fill data report in parameter
            var rds4 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityEventTotal", (DataTable)ds4.GetData(operationDate)); //fill data report in parameter
            var rds5 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityNoteDailyReport", (DataTable)ds5.GetData(operationDate)); ///fill data report in parameter
            var rds6 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityDailyReport", (DataTable)ds6.GetData(operationDate)); //fill data report in parameter
            var rds7 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityReadingTotal", (DataTable)ds7.GetData(operationDate)); //fill data report in parameter
            var rds8 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityEventSum1", (DataTable)ds8.GetData(operationDate)); //fill data report in parameter
            var rds9 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityEventSum2", (DataTable)ds9.GetData(operationDate)); //fill data report in parameter
            var rds10 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityEventSum3", (DataTable)ds10.GetData(operationDate)); //fill data report in parameter

            // Variables
            Warning[] warnings;
            string[] streamIds;
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            string extension = string.Empty;


            // Setup the report viewer object and get the array of bytes
            var report = new LocalReport();
            report.ReportPath = reportPath;
            report.DataSources.Add(rds); // Add datasource here
            report.DataSources.Add(rds2); // Add datasource here
            report.DataSources.Add(rds3); // Add datasource here
            report.DataSources.Add(rds4); // Add datasource here
            report.DataSources.Add(rds5); // Add datasource here
            report.DataSources.Add(rds6); // Add datasource here
            report.DataSources.Add(rds7); // Add datasource here
            report.DataSources.Add(rds8); // Add datasource here
            report.DataSources.Add(rds9); // Add datasource here
            report.DataSources.Add(rds10); // Add datasource here

            //set parameter report (jika ada)
            report.SetParameters(new List<ReportParameter> 
            {
                //new ReportParameter("FacilitySubClassID", facilitySubClassId.ToString()),
                new ReportParameter("OperationDate", operationDate.ToString())
            });


            byte[] bytes = report.Render(reportType, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);


            // Now that you have all the bytes representing the PDF report, buffer it and send it to the client.
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Clear();
            Response.ContentType = mimeType;
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "." + extension + "\"");
            Response.BinaryWrite(bytes); // create the file
            Response.Flush(); // send it to the client to download
        }
```

I have a sub-report on my rdlc report,, when i tried to export it to excel. The error message appear on excel file (sub-report section).

```
"Data retrieval failed for the subreport, 'srAvailabilityList', located at: C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\coco\rdlc\availabilityreading.rdlc. Please check the log files for more information."
```

The sub-report is using `ds6` and `ds7`.

My questions are:

- How can I retrieve the data in the sub-report?
- Where I can find the log files?

Comment: Log files are at your equivalent of `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS11.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\LogFiles`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
        void MySubreportEventHandler(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {
            var operationDate = System.DateTime.ParseExact(txtStartDate.Text, "dd/MMM/yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            var ds6 = new _spAvailabilityDailyReportTableAdapter();
            var ds7 = new _spAvailabilityReadingTotalTableAdapter();
            var rds6 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityDailyReport", (DataTable)ds6.GetData(operationDate)); //isi data report di parameter kedua
            var rds7 = new ReportDataSource("dsAvailabilityReadingTotal", (DataTable)ds7.GetData(operationDate)); //isi data report di parameter kedua

            e.DataSources.Add(rds6);
            e.DataSources.Add(rds7);
        }
```

Then add this code before `report.SetParameter` :

```
report.SubreportProcessing += new SubreportProcessingEventHandler(MySubreportEventHandler);
```

Comment: The part about adding the event handler before setparameter did the trick for me. Thanks